# PHP not fetching data from MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making a comment box, in which

- Comment box will be under the post
- Every comment box has the same id as the post has
- That's why i preffered to do a `while` loop

But, the problem is

- As i'm using a `fetch_assoc()` method, some comment tables will be empty so 
  i've made a if else code for them

Here is my if else code :

```
$select_comment_table = "SELECT * FROM feed_comment_" . $row['id'] . "ORDER BY id";
$result_query_select_comment_table = $dbc->query($select_comment_table);
if(!$result_query_select_comment_table) {
    $result_select_comment_table = array("full_name" => "", "comment"=> "No comments yet.");

}
else {
    $result_select_comment_table = $result_query_select_comment_table->fetch_assoc();
}
```

If other code is need :

```
echo '<div id="feed_comment_box_' . $row['id'] . '"' . 'class="feed_comment_box_cl"><div id="add_comment_id" class="add_comment_cl">
<form class="comment_form" method="post" action="' .$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']  . '">
<input name="comment_full_name" type="text" class="input_comment_full_name">  </input> 
<textarea name="input_comment_text" type="text" class="input_comment_text" ></textarea><input name="comment_submit" type="submit"></input> <br>
 </form>
</div><br>
<div id="comment_box_id" class="comment_box_cl">
<table tabindex="0" class="comment_box"> 
<tr> <td class="comment_full_name">' . $result_select_comment_table["full_name"] . '</td></tr><br>' . 
'<tr> <td class="comment_full_name">' . $result_select_comment_table["comment"] . '</td></tr><br>'
. '</table></div></div>';
echo '</div>';
```

Problem : As you see the `if else` code, the php should echo `no comments yet` when there is no comment. But, even after inserting the comment(i tried manually insert in database) it is showing `no comments yet` whereas it should show the comments 
Note: I am using a while loop that's why the comment div is coming under every post.

Comment: Please show code including this while loop you say you are using, otherwise the prose and the code dont match. Thanks

Comment: This is just malformed SQL text.  This is very easily debugged by simply echoing out the dynamically generated SQL text; it's very clear that the SQL statement is invalid because there is no space between the table_name and the `ORDER` keyword, it looks like `ORDER` is part of the table name identifier. That leaves the keyword `BY` all by it's lonesome, and that's syntax error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're missing a space in your query:

```
$select_comment_table = "SELECT * FROM feed_comment_" . $row['id'] . "ORDER BY id";
```

should be

```
$select_comment_table = "SELECT * FROM feed_comment_" . $row['id'] . " ORDER BY id";
```

The invalid query is causing $result_query_select_comment_table to always be false.

Comment: Right before ORDER BY

Comment: @MihirUjjainwal: between the table_name and the `ORDER` keyword. Echo out your SQL text, you'll spot it real fast.

Comment: Got it, this problem made me confused for more than an hour.

Comment: Are you sure this is the real problem? OP needs to inform possible error if there any MySQL syntax error inside it

Comment: @MihirUjjainwal, did this solve your problem? If it did, please accept the answer.